# What USB-2 cabling hardware do I need to connect two Windows 10 computers together?

Tags: usb, communication, usb-device, usb-host, windows

I want to run a .NET app in each of the two computers, so that they send and receive data through USB-2.

What kind of cable adapter will do this?

BACKGROUND:
I need to build a GUI on Windows that communicates through USB-2 with an embedded EFM32 ARM on our embedded board, which is not available yet.  so, I want to simulate the embedded with a .NET app running on my Windows 10 laptop and communicating through USB-2 to my .NET app GUI running on my Windows 10 desktop.

Comment: Generally two computers can't communicate directly via USB, as both are USB hosts. USB host can only communicate with USB device, so you will need at least one in the middle.

Comment: What protocol does the embedded board use to communicate with the host PC? There may be easier ways to do this.

Comment: Let's say that you need to receive data through only one USB. How are you doing this? Is it through serial port? If so, why not use something like PuTTY and just open up two sessions with two different USBs going into your devices? If your answer is that your ARM does not have two USBs, then what's preventing you from using a USB hub?

Comment: There are a plethora of Host-Host transfer cable available like this: http://www.usbgear.com/windows-10-data-transfer-cable.html  Search for Duolink, netlink or similar will bring up more options. There are also 'cables' that offer USB-on-the-go functionality that are even more flexible. Buying one of the 'cables' that implement as a shared disk drive is probably the easiest way to go, your application then needs only to write or read from a disk drive.

Comment: The question literally asked is not on topic here, because it is about networking between computer systems, not about electrical engineering.  In terms of the original goal which might be on topic if it had been the question asked, once you are simulating you might as well just use another process on the same host or else pass the traffic over Ethernet - the accuracy of any interface dynamics would depend more on how you modeled them, you can't really assume that some different hardware interface (even if USB) would accurately model the one your program eventually needs to work across.

Comment: The question title needs to be re-formulated in accord with actual goal stated in OP's "BACKGROUND" section, something like "How to emulate a proprietary USB device using Windows laptop"?

Comment: Eugene Sh: I plan to program an embedded simulation that has a USB device driver on one side (ie. laptop) and a GUI that has USB host on the other (ie. desktop), so that when embedded hardware is done, GUI will already be tested and ready.  JACK CREASEY:  Thanks!  CHRIS STATTON: True, but will probably take less development time to get desktop/laptop running than to loopback USB on same computer, which I would PREFER to do.

Comment: Jack B:  Like I said: USB-2

Comment: KingDuken: You don't understand USB vs. RS232

Comment: @DougNull - no, involving USB especially in an unusual way will make this inordinately harder.  If you want an efficiently built stand-in, don't use USB, use their the loopback network interface or the real one.  Or else use something approaching the real embedded hardware with its actual USB interface.  The available file transfer bridging cables for connecting two computers via USB are doing to be too drastically different from your end USB situation to be of practical use; using the ordinary network would be better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a commendable desire to emulate your device in development to proceed ahead with software development before the hardware is ready. It is a challenging problem. But you can't simulate a USB device on a regular Windows host. USB host has special functions of "hosting" the bus, which are incompatible with USB slave device functions. No "cabling hardware" can help here. The host functions are hardware-based, usually adhere to strict hardware specifications (Intel EHCI or xHCI), and cannot be turned around.

Some tablets/laptops may have an USB OTG (or dual-role-data function), and act as USB devices if connected to another USB host with correct OTG cable. To make this happen, the system must have an alternative USB device controller, another piece of hardware. However, these OTG Device controllers usually have hardware-predefined structure of endpoints (usually implementing MTP or Mass-Storage Class), and it is very unlikely that the built-in configuration will match your proprietary "embedded EFM32 ARM" enpoint structure, or can be re-programmed.

If your team is designing some proprietary "embedded EFM32 ARM" USB interface, which doesn't follow any predefined USB class, you are out of luck regarding software development in advance. While there are environments that allow virtualization of the system, you will still need to develop a transaction-based model of your "embedded EFM32 ARM" device, which will likely take time, be inaccurate, and can't be trusted. The more natural way would be to get a EFM32 development platform from Silicon Labs, and modify their existing codes to mimic your "embedded EFM32 ARM" device where possible.